# aerospike client and server

Tags: node.js, client, aerospike

I'm facing a problem with aerospike.

I have two nodes cluster having IP `192.168.1.2` and `192.168.1.3`

My aerospike nodejs client is configured with `192.168.1.2` but when i restart this node. then my client is unable to connect with cluster.

**question 1**: should i add multipal IPs on client?

**question 2**: if i need to add multipal IPs what happen when i will add another node into the cluster? I have to edit my client configuration?

**question 3**: assume i add 3rd node which ip is : `192.168.1.4`. What is the steps or to add this node into this cluster? I need to edit every existing node configuration file and add  mesh-seed-address-port `192.168.1.4 3002`?

Note: My aerospike is configured with default configuration. I just added mesh-seed-address-port `192.168.1.2 3002` & mesh-seed-address-port `192.168.1.3 3002` on each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide both IP addresses. When one node is down the client will timeout on connecting to it, and try the other IP address. It only needs one successful connection to 'seed' the cluster (meaning it learns about the other nodes and partition table at that point), so it stops after the first that works.

```
var config = {
  hosts: [
    { addr: '192.168.1.2', port: 3000 },
    { addr: '192.168.1.3', port: 3000 }
  ]
}
```

For bigger cluster people usually set up a nameserver (such as BIND) and serve up one of the IPs using round-robin. That allows you to put the hostname as the address, which is a cleaner approach. A nameserver allows you to add and drop node IPs with a delay without being too worried.

As for (3) you can provide several [mesh-seed-address-port](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#mesh-seed-address-port) lines, so that if one is not available you can still have a node added to the cluster. Look at [Mesh (Unicast) Heartbeat](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/heartbeat/#mesh-unicast-heartbeat) for more information. The new node needs to be in `mode mesh` and have an explicit IP `address`.  If you don't *have* to use mesh, it's better to use [multicast](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/heartbeat/#multicast-heartbeat) for heartbeats.

Comment: I Will use aws so that multicast is not possible.

Comment: I understood that. I meant in general, you can either use mesh or multicast.

Comment: another question is if 1 node is up and running with 100 GB of data and then I add another 1 node into the cluster. then how many time is required to rebalance all things (replication factor 2)? (approximately) and when rebalance occur on that time is cluster will serve any client request?